# Inno Setup: Ask for reboot after uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I would like to ask the user to reboot the system, after the application has been uninstalled.

By using `AlwaysRestart=yes` the user gets only asked after the installation, but the prompt doesn't appear afterwards.

I am using Inno Setup to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UninstallNeedRestart` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=UninstallNeedRestart):

```pascal
function UninstallNeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

It makes uninstaller ask for reboot at the end.

[image]

Note that you cannot combine this with the [`AlwaysRestart` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_alwaysrestart).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I experienced inno-setup to display a second message box asking for reboot, so it is probably just nessary to return True: Like

Comment: Result:= True; inno-setup will then ask anyway.

Comment: He wanted the user being asked after Uninstall not after Install. As I understood it, AlwaysRestart is for rebooting after Install, not after uninstall.

Comment: We are using inno-setup for our WinDRBD driver (a port of Linbit's DRBD Linux driver, see https://github.com/LINBIT/windrbd): This installation does not require a reboot after Install but it (currently still) requires a reboot after Uninstall to remove the driver from the System (which would currently BSOD, we are working on this)

Comment: @JohannesThoma OK, I see now. I've updated my answer. Thanks.